# How do I add a stock level updated date to the front end

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

I currently have the following code that displays the quantity of the product being viewed:

```
<?php 
echo intval(Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()); 
?>
```

This all works fine, but what I would like to do is get the last updated date of this Stock Quanity, is this possible?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score -1):

Hello i create query may be help you

**$sqlcategory = "SELECT updated_at FROM sales_flat_order_item  WHERE product_id='51' order by updated_at DESC limit 1";
             $datacategory = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')->fetchAll($sqlcategory);
echo $datacategory[0]['updated_at'];**

Comment: sales_flat_order_item  is sales table not item table